# Including and excluding extensions -- PHP installation

Tags: php, linux, web, php5

Note: This question is not only about the PEAR extension, it is **in general**.

I disabled the PEAR extension by installing PHP on CentOS server with the following command:

`$ yum php --without-pear`

Now I want to use the extension PEAR. Please answer the following question:

**What is the command for installing a extension which was not installed during the PHP installation?**

Note: I'm looking for a solution which does not involve PHP re-installation.

Comment: I know, you are talking about extension "in general", but pear is not a regular extension, because its completely written in PHP and can be downloaded "as it is" from the pear homepage.

Comment: Thanks you for the comment. I accept your comment for PEAR. But what about other extensions? I skipped many during installation and now I want to use those extensions. I mentioned only PEAR just for the simplicity of the question.

Answer (score 1):

PECL is the PHP extension library with a commandline installer for all available pecl extensions. You can find all information on the official pecl website: http://pecl.php.net/

Installing a pecl extension is as simple as running `pecl install extensionname` from the commandline. You might need to install php5-pear and php5-devel with apt or yum before you get access to the pecl command though, all depends on your current setup.

It might also be worth noting that pecl is based on the PEAR packaging system, so no PEAR is no PECL as far as I know.